# Unable to scrape this site. How to scrape data from this site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Iam not able to scrape data from this site.

I tried with other sites but it's ok with other sites...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen("https://www.daraz.com.np/catalog/?spm=a2a0e.searchlistcategory.search.2.3eac4b8amQJ0zd&q=samsung%20m20&_keyori=ss&from=suggest_normal&sugg=samsung%20m20_1_1")

html = response.read()

parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

containers = parsed_html.find_all("div", {"class" : "c2prKC"})

print(len(containers))
```

Answer (score 4):

Look like JS render to page after loading .You can use Selenium to render the page and beautiful soup to get the element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.daraz.com.np/catalog/?spm=a2a0e.searchlistcategory.search.2.3eac4b8amQJ0zd&q=samsung%20m20&_keyori=ss&from=suggest_normal&sugg=samsung%20m20_1_1")
time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source

parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

containers = parsed_html.find_all("div", {"class" : "c2prKC"})

print(len(containers))
```

Answer (score 3):

Info you want is in a script tag. You can use regex or loop script tags to get the right string to parse as json (with a small amendment)

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
res = requests.get('https://www.daraz.com.np/catalog/?spm=a2a0e.searchlistcategory.search.2.3eac4b8amQJ0zd&q=samsung%20m20&_keyori=ss&from=suggest_normal&sugg=samsung%20m20_1_1', headers = headers)
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
for script in soup.select('script'):
    if 'window.pageData=' in script.text:
        script = script.text.replace('window.pageData=','')
        break
items = json.loads(script)['mods']['listItems']
results = []

for item in items:
    #print(item)
    #extract other info you want
    row = [item['name'], item['priceShow'], item['productUrl'], item['ratingScore']]
    results.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Name', 'Price', 'ProductUrl', 'Rating'])

print(df.head())
```

---

**Regex version:**

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
res = requests.get('https://www.daraz.com.np/catalog/?spm=a2a0e.searchlistcategory.search.2.3eac4b8amQJ0zd&q=samsung%20m20&_keyori=ss&from=suggest_normal&sugg=samsung%20m20_1_1', headers = headers)
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r'window.pageData=(.*)')
data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
script = r.findall(data)[0]
items = json.loads(script)['mods']['listItems']
results = []

for item in items:
    row = [item['name'], item['priceShow'], item['productUrl'], item['ratingScore']]
    results.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Name', 'Price', 'ProductUrl', 'Rating'])

print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
res = requests.get('https://www.daraz.com.np/catalog/?q=camera&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2a0e.searchlist.search.go.71a64360Kgxf1m', headers = headers)
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
scriptData=''
for d in containerSearch:
    if 'window.pageData=' in str(d):
        scriptData=str(d).replace('window.pageData=','')
        break
scriptData=scriptData.replace('<script>','')
scriptData=scriptData.replace('</script>','')
items = json.loads(scriptData)
name=items['mods']['listItems'][0]['name']
image=items['mods']['listItems'][0]['image']
price=items['mods']['listItems'][0]['price']
priceShow=items['mods']['listItems'][0]['priceShow']
ratingScore=items['mods']['listItems'][0]['ratingScore']
productUrl=items['mods']['listItems'][0]['productUrl']

print(name)
print(price)
```