# Failure to access different pages with (python) selenium vs direct access

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am quite puzzled with this code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time


PATH = 'My_path_to/chromedriver'



for i in range(3):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    url = 'https://www.daraz.pk/laptops/?page='+str(i+1)
    print(url)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

Even thought the link is each time correctly written in the navigation bar, it shows always the page 1, but when I click on the printed links, the display is correct... Is it a javascript artefact to stop web scraping? Is it possible to overcome it?

Comment: That is very strange.  I see what you are saying.  Even adding a `driver.refresh()` to each loop doesn't change the items displayed.  I'd be curious to see if someone comes up with a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use selenium to **scrape** daraz.pk
Use requests, page source has a json object that you can parse using json and let pandas export it to a csv file.
Following code does the job for one page.
You may way to unpack the dictionary to show all information on first level in csv file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import *
import json
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame((json.loads([x for x in BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.daraz.pk/laptops/?page=1').content, 'html.parser').findAll('script') if 'window.pageData' in x.text][0].text.split('window.pageData=')[1]))['mods']['listItems']).to_csv('page1.csv', index=False)
```

This should make more sense:

```
import requests
from bs4 import *
import json
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://www.daraz.pk/laptops/?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
json_data = [x for x in soup.findAll('script') if 'window.pageData' in x.text][0].text.split('window.pageData=')[1]
json_object = json.loads(json_data)
listed_items_dict = json_object['mods']['listItems']
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(listed_items_dict)
dataframe.to_csv('page1.csv', index=False)
```

Based on the comment use this function. It uses requests and sends cookie with request and this will return a dictionary of listed items.

```
def get_page_ajax(n):
    headers = {
        'authority': 'www.daraz.pk',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'referer': 'https://www.daraz.pk/laptops/?page=1',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cookie': 'cna=OZ/WFbQKLVwCAbKZLti/7Hsq; _scid=7861a3f6-8fc7-4051-8f21-7ff77b830e4f; lzd_cid=84c13174-852a-4f95-ed5d-a8dcdd6767bb; t_uid=84c13174-852a-4f95-ed5d-a8dcdd6767bb; lzd_sid=1ba989d0707604107e91e9001996d1fd; _tb_token_=5e88e18541b9f; hng=PK|en-PK|PKR|586; userLanguageML=en-PK; t_fv=1619138165830; _gcl_au=1.1.1640796331.1619138166; _ga=GA1.2.213815672.1619138167; _gid=GA1.2.1272622655.1619138167; __auc=3682a279178fc27bf6267d1df0c; _bl_uid=h1kzbndntF4lIg2hX9vq1m1oLdU0; _sctr=1|1619125200000; xlly_s=1; t_sid=oBnSCDmQiPyrQNhDz6NRhBUUjfRvyUHF; utm_channel=NA; daraz-marketing-tracker=hide; _m_h5_tk=a8d8092d608b9889dec7cefccdc3b351_1619183643275; _m_h5_tk_enc=068447fd0471b8537f47a430f7fe4128; __asc=f4f31b38178fe5456d962e14446; _gat_UA-31709783-1=1; JSESSIONID=7A1B772A77330A06B2D19937BDE5775B; tfstk=ctmcBmfEqqzb16zoRnZjhTB12gpRZYSatcoS4cfIen_xLumPiBQP80ByEScmXN1..; l=eBM3wODljUtubHaFBO5whurza77OUIOf1sPzaNbMiInca1uO6wI2zNCCg036JdtjQtf0uetzd4S4yReM7rzU-xNbmbKe6QuI2ov6-; isg=BMvLGwrYLxDvEE44amWSgStYWm-1YN_ieR8y9T3J-YoyXOi-xTPLM_26NkSy_Dfa',
    }

    params = (
        ('ajax', 'true'),
        ('page', str(n)),
    )

    response = requests.get('https://www.daraz.pk/laptops/', headers=headers, params=params)    
    json_object = json.loads(response.content.decode())
    listed_items_dict = json_object['mods']['listItems']
    return listed_items_dict
```

Comment: If fact selenium is needed because the html is rendered after the JS is applied : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533589/unable-to-scrape-this-site-how-to-scrape-data-from-this-site

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code, but still don't know what the problem is. The pages is displayed correctly by what I've noticed that there is no difference in the elements shown in the first and second page but the third has another elements shown. I don't now why but I've visited the URL manually and got the same result.

Comment: The json object returned in each page is same. The trick is to use requests but also send cookie with each request and call the ajax endpoint. It returns a json object that can be parsed directly to be exported to CSV.

Comment: I have made changes to the answer based on your comment. The function works as expected.